# How to add custom fields to ModelView (flask-appbuild)

Tags: python, flask, flask-appbuilder

I'm a newby in webdevoloping and tried myself with flask-appbuilder.

I've defined a model and also a modelview, the table is displayed nicely on the webapp.

I want to add some custom fields (dropdown and a button) if I hit the detail view of an item, but I've really no idea how to achieve this.

I went through the flask-appbuilder guide, but didn't find anything useful.

```
class RegionView(ModelView):
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(Region)
```

```
class Region(Model):
    __tablename__ = "region"
    region_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    region_domain = Column(String(100), unique=True)
    region_description = Column(String(100))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Region(region_id = {rid}, region_domain = {rdo}, region_description = {rde}, type = {type})".format(rid=self.region_id,rdo = self.region_domain, rde = self.region_description, type=self.type)
```

I'm also getting the webapp not to work, if **init** method is defined. Is there any possibility to use the constructor or do i need to implement a custom method?

I want to add a dropdown and a button. If I hit the button, a function delivers some data and they should be displayed in a textfield.

current: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tD7Rl.jpg
target: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zoV7.jpg

I'm grateful for any help!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but for those who are wondering how to add buttons, links, ... you can see this example:
https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/blob/master/examples/quickfiles/app/models.py

Inside the model is defined a download method which will return a "Markup" defining a link (could be a button):

```
    def download(self):
        return Markup(
            '<a href="'
            + url_for("ProjectFilesModelView.download", filename=str(self.file))
            + '">Download</a>'
        )
```